# EF Core multiple (dynamic) columns with equal data type

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-core

*Please excuse me for bad title. I couldn't think of any better. Feel free to suggest a better one in comments.*

I have a case, where I need to have a dynamic number of columns. In my example addresses.
One customer want 1 address and other wants 7 (bill address, deliver address, bid address, bill address, confirmation address ...). I do not want to create all possible columns for all application setups. But provide some sort of mechanism that every user should set (in program) how many and which information's they need.

I know entity framework do not support dynamic tables. But I am sure many had the same problem. Maybe `string[]` would suite best, but EF Core doesn't support it.
I could store all addresses in JSON, but then I loose options to filter and sort by this columns in SQL (LINQ).

Is there any common pattern to achieve dynamic columns and keep server filtering (maybe ordering)?

Comment: With '.net core 2.0.0' and 'EF Core 2.0.0', you can use 'System.Linq.Dynamic' namespace and get your job done !

Comment: I heard for System.Linq.Dynamic but as far as I know, this is for queering with string parameter, but not how object that represent row should be defined.

Comment: What you need to do is de-normalize your data